# Adding a class to current page in list of siblings - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I have a custom sidebar that is populated by a list of the current page's siblings.  I would like to add a class to the current page in this list so that I can highlight it in the list.  I am creating the sidebar like this:

```
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 button-column">
                            <?php

                                $siblingArgs = [
                                    'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
                                    'hierarchical' =>  0,
                                    'parent' => $post->post_parent,
                                ];

                                $siblingPages = get_pages($siblingArgs);
                                $currentChildren = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

                                foreach ($siblingPages as $siblingPage) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $siblingPage->guid ?>" class="body-button"><?php echo $siblingPage->post_title ?></a>
                                    <?php if($siblingPage->ID == $post->ID && (!empty($currentChildren))) {
                                        echo '<ul class="hidden-list hidden-box">';
                                        foreach ($currentChildren as $child){
                                            echo '<li><a href="';
                                            echo $child->guid.'">';
                                            echo $child->post_title.'</a></li>';
                                        };
                                        echo '</ul>';
                                    };
                                endforeach; ?>
                        </div><!--end column-->
```

I am trying to figure out the easiest way to add a class to the current page in the sidebar list.  Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please de-indent your code so it's not far off to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS you can get the current page URL then find the anchor tag in document(current page) and add class ('active') or whatever class you want

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $("a[href$='" + pathname + "']").addClass('yourClassNameHere');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [body_class()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) in your body tag eg.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

it will generate unique body classes according to current page:

```
<body class="page page-id-2 page-parent page-template-default logged-in">
```

and then in the css you can make your selector

```
.page-id-2 .side_bar_global_class { /* Rules here */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm working on a 400 page site, so that would be 400 CSS declarations.  I am looking for a way to dynamically add a class within my PHP to the sibling that is the current page